# How to use lower case of enum as index key type in typrescrpt

Tags: typescript

How to use lower case of enum as index key type in typrescrpt?
I have a enum like below

```
export enum NameSet {
  Taxi = 'Taxi ',
  Bus = 'Bus',
  Empty = '',
}
```

I would like to type a object to have key based on the lower case of NameSet like below

```
   type ITraffic = {
      [K in NameSet.toLowerCase()]?: string
    }
```

But obviously, this is not a correct.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAcghhYBlYAXKBvAUFKAVOADwEsoBeKAcgJKoBocoAhMAZ3KpdcodwFEIAB1QBPDpR5YAvliwB6OVFGDgUAJJ4ATnABmO4gGMO2BbigAiVEVLmA-AC4orVJuIgA5lAA+UMCAAmwPogwP4A3PKKuABGbA5OLm6ePn6BwaERprjmdo7Orh7evgFBbhmRUDLKqhraeobGjADaANJQbrAIyGhQcOwAMgD2AO7AmgZ9wAA8LQB8ALrx+UkRUhFAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can map through NameSet and make an object with lowercase keys like this:

```
   type ITraffic = {
      [K in NameSet as Lowercase<K>]?: string
    }
```

And if you want no key-value for empty case, you can do this:

```
   type ITraffic = {
      [K in NameSet as K extends '' ? never : Lowercase<K>]?: string
    }
```